# cannot migrate app using south

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-south

i installed south for my project and ran the command

```
manage.py schemamigration mysite --initial
```

in my terminal and it is giving-

```
aquaman@aquamanpc:~/mysite$ python manage.py schemamigration mysite --initial
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399,   in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/management/commands/schemamigration.py", line 73, in handle
migrations = Migrations(app, force_creation=True, verbose_creation=verbosity > 0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 60, in __call__
self.instances[app_label] = super(MigrationsMetaclass, self).__call__(app_label_to_app_module(app_label), **kwds)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/utils.py", line 41, in app_label_to_app_module
app = models.get_app(app_label)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 190, in get_app
raise ImproperlyConfigured("App with label %s could not be found" % app_label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label mysite could not be found
```

and my settings.py-

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'south',
'mysite',
```

)

help me please where i m wrong

i m new to django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `'mysite'` app to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in the **setting.py**